Functional equation of the Hecke L function in ideal term and "ideal number" term (Neukirch Chapter VII)
$\def\A{\mathbb{A}}
\def\B{\mathbb{B}}
\def\C{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\Cx}{\mathbb{C}^{\times}}
\def\F{\mathbb{F}}
\def\G{\mathbb{G}}
\def\H{\mathbb{H}}
\def\K{\mathbb{K}}
\def\M{\mathbb{M}}
\def\N{\mathbb{N}}
\def\O{\mathcal{O}}
\def\P{\mathbb{P}}
\def\Q{\mathbb{Q}}
\def\R{\mathbb{R}}
\def\T{\mathbb{T}}
\def\V{\mathbb{V}}
\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}
\def\fin{\mathrm{fin}}
\def\x{^{\times}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}$
Let $F$ be a number field with degree $n$. Let $r_1$ be the number of real primes and $r_2$ be the number of complex primes. For a non-zero integral ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $F$, we put
$
I_F(\mathfrak{m})=\{a \in I_F \mid(a, \mathfrak{m})=1\}
$ where $I_F$ be the group of fractional ideals of $F$.
First we would like to recall the definition of a
Grössencharacter.
Let $\mathcal{O}_F(\mathfrak{m})$ be the integers of $F$ that are prime to $\mathfrak{m}$.

Definition. A group homomorphism $\psi:I_F(\mathfrak{m})\to\C\x$ is called the (Hecke)
Grössencharacter of $\bmod{\mathfrak{m}}$ if it satisfies the following condition:
There exist a character $$\psi_{\fin}:(\mathcal{O}_F/\mathfrak{m})\x\to\C\x$$ and complex numbers $u_v, w_v\left(1 \leqq v \leqq r_1+r_2\right)$ such that $u_v \in \begin{cases}\{0,1\} & \left(v \leqq r_1\right) \\ \mathbb{Z} & \left(r_1+1 \leqq v\right)\end{cases}$, so that
$$\psi((\alpha))=\psi_{\fin}(\alpha)\psi_{\infty}(\alpha)\ (\alpha\in\mathcal{O}_F(\mathfrak{m})).$$
Where
$$
 \psi_{\infty}(a):=\prod_{v=1}^{r_1+r_2}\left(a_v /\left|a_v\right|\right)^{u_v}\left|a_v\right|^{w_v}
 $$
$\psi_{\fin}$ and $\psi_{\infty}$ are called the finite and infinite parts of $\psi$, respectively. $u_v, w_v\left(1 \leqq v \leqq r_1+r_2\right)$ are called infinite type of $\psi$.

Now let $\psi$ be a unitary primitive Grössencharacter of conductor $\mathfrak{f}$ with infinite type $u_v, iv_v\left(v_v\in\R, 1 \leqq v \leqq r_1+r_2\right)$ and $v_1+\cdots +v_{r_1+r_2}=0$ (I have been confusing since some auther don't require this condition). The following are quoted from Miyake "Modular Forms" p.90.
Let $\mathfrak{c}$ be an integral ideal of $F$ such that $\mathfrak{d}_F\mathfrak{f}\mathfrak{c}$ ($\mathfrak{d}_F$ be the different ideal of $F$) is principal and $(\mathfrak{f}, \mathfrak{c})=1$. Take an element $b$ of $\mathcal{O}_F$ so that $\mathfrak{d}_F\mathfrak{f}\mathfrak{c}=(b)$, and define the Gauss sum $G(\psi)$ of $\psi$ by
$$
G(\psi)=\frac{\psi_{\infty}(b)}{\psi(\mathfrak{c})} \sum_{[a]\in \mathfrak{c} / \mathfrak{m}\mathfrak{c}} \psi_{\fin}(a) e^{2 \pi i \Tr_{F/\Q}(a / b)}.
$$ The value $G(\psi)$ is independent of the choice of $\mathfrak{c}, b$ and a set of representatives. We put
$$
\Lambda(s, \psi)=\left(\frac{2^{r_1}\left|D_F\right| N(\mathfrak{f})}{(2 \pi)^n}\right)^{s / 2} \prod_{v=1}^{r_1+r_2} \Gamma\left(\frac{n_v s+\left|u_v\right|+i v_v}{2}\right) L(s, \psi),
$$
where
$$
n_v= \begin{cases}1 & \left(v \leqq r_1\right) \\ 2 & \left(r_1+1 \leqq v\right) .\end{cases}
$$
Now the functional equation for a Hecke $L$-function is as follows.

Theorem. Let $\psi$ be a primitive
Grössencharacter of conductor $\mathfrak{f}$. $\Lambda(s, \psi)$ is analytically continued to a meromorphic function on the whole $s$-plane, and satisfies the functional equation
where
$$
\Lambda(1-s, \psi)=T(\psi) \Lambda(s, \bar{\psi})
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
T(\psi) & =\frac{2^{i (v_{r_1+1} +\cdots +v_{r_1+r_2})} G(\psi)}{i^{u_1+\cdots +u_{r_1+r_2}}\mathcal{N}(\mathfrak{f})^{1 / 2}}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Now in Neukirch "Algebraic number theory", it is formulated by using the notion of "ideal numbers". For this notion, I want you to see this question which is perhaps useful information.
First $m,d$ be the ideal number defined by the following:

Then the functional equation is stated as follows:


Question1. Please show me the proof of the each formulation of Miyake and Neukirch are equivalent.
Question2. Please show me the proof of the functional equation formulated by ideal (not Tate's thesis).

What you call Question 1 and Question 2 are not questions ("Let me..." is not asking anything).  Write more clearly what you it is you are asking and what you have already done.

Hmm OK, I haven't merely found the proof (Miyake's book doesn't include the proof and I don't know what is original source). I just ask you to prove these. What I have done is searching various materials including Hecke's old text book but I haven't found what I really want. Also, Miyake's $W(\chi)$ has a term of power of $2$, but Neukirch 's one seems not to have power of $2$, and I have bit anxiety for whether they are really equivalent.

More, in Neukirch's proof, beautiful function the Hecke theta series appears in ideal number term (it seems to be hidden in Tate's thesis). I also hope for knowing it by ideal term.
